# Best way to query postgres db from django to list all users (tab1) which have active book borrows (tab2)?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have a simple application in Django. The simple logic is kind of book library.

Tab1. stores the users:

```python
class Readers(Model):  
    last_name = CharField(...)  
    first_name = CharField(...)
```

Tab2. stores the book borrows:

```python
class BookBorrows(Model):  
    index = IntegerField(db_index=True, ...)  
    reader = ForeignKey('Reader', ...)  
    book = ForeignKey('Book', ...)
    active = BooleanField(...)
```

I am struggling to figure out what is the proper solution to get:

1. List of all Readers with at least one borrowed book (the field active==True).
2. List of all Readers without any currently borrowed book (the field active==False).

After some serche I am thinking about django `.raw('QUERY ...')` or maybe is there a more django-friendly way to achieve this?

P.S.:this is my first question posted to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reader_ids_with_book = BookBorrows.objects.filter(active=True).values_list(
    'reader_id', flat=True
)

readers_without_book = Readers.objects.exclude(id__in=list(reader_ids_with_book))
```

first query gives you the valuelist queryset of users who borrowed at least one book and you can use this in order to find out other users who didnot borrow anything yet

Comment: Thanks. Additionally i have combined it with `.distinct()` and have reached my goal.